# Is there array_count_values() analogue for Python 3.x or best way to do this?

Tags: python

Is there array_count_values() analogue or fastest way to do this in Python 3.x

from

```
d = ["1", "this", "1", "is", "Sparta", "Sparta"]
```

to

```
{
  '1': 2,
  'this': 1,
  'is': 1,
  'Sparta': 2
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can count the occurrence of each element in a list using `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

l = [1, "this", 1, "is", "Sparta", "Sparta"]
print(Counter(l))
```

This prints

```
Counter({1: 2, 'Sparta': 2, 'this': 1, 'is': 1})
```

[repl.it link](https://repl.it/DpTq)

Comment: Your correction is still invalid. You cannot pass arguments like that to `list()`. In your case, you would create a list using `[]`